What is the level of support for Guamanian independence among different groups?
Guam is a US territory that does not have voting rights in US general elections. There have been several referenda to assess support for a change to independent or state status, but none recently.
Several decades back, there was a proposal by the government to hold a plebiscite that would only be open to people whose ancestors had acquired citizenship through the Organic Law; however, this proposal was struck down by a circuit court, which viewed it as a proxy for CHamoru ethnicity. Demographically, a plurality of residents are Chamorro or CHamoru, while about a quarter are of Filipino descent and the rest mainly from other parts of Asia and Micronesia and the USA.
That might lead one to infer higher support for independence among CHamoru residents of Guam than among Filipinos and others; however, historically, independence received relatively little support, so it may not be so obvious.
Has there been any research done on how support for independence varies between different demographics in Guam?

As of 2016, support for independence was very much a minority opinion and a plurality of Guamanian voters wanted statehood. I didn't dig for the full study to see if it breaks down demographics. https://www.kuam.com/story/31747261/2016/04/Sunday/uog-poll-guamanians-prefer-statehood

Some context: Guam wiki:  540sq km, 168k pop.

They're effectively living off the US taxpayers back, so support for independence would be very low. Independent pacific islands are impoverished places.

@JonathanReez Somewhat reductionist, if partially true.  Guam houses important US Navy and Air Force bases and can consequently look forward to being a parking lot for Chinese missiles in the event of a US-China war.  i.e. the US does benefit from the relationship as well.
